# Suppose $f$ is continuous and $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt$ bounded on $[a,b)$. Does $\lim_{x \to b^{-}} F(x)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

> Suppose $f$ is continuous and $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) \ \mathrm{d}t$ bounded on $[a,b)$. 
> Does $\lim_{x \to b^{-}} F(x)$ exist?

Since $F$ is bounded on $[a,b)$, there exists $L > 0$ such that

$$-L \leq F(x) \leq L$$

for all $x \in [a,b)$. taking the limits

$$\lim_{x \to b^{-}} - L \leq \lim_{x \to b^{-}} F(x) \leq \lim_{x \to b^{-}} L$$
$$- L \leq \lim_{x \to b^{-}} F(x) \leq L$$

The squeeze theorem cannot be used since $-L \neq L$. Must this be true?

Comment: Take any continuously differentiable and  bounded function $F$ on $[a, b)$ for which the limit $\lim_{x \to b^{-}} F(x)$ does not exist, and set $f = F'$. For example, $F(x) = \sin(1/x)$ on $[-1, 0)$.

Answer (score 3):

Take any continuously differentiable and bounded function $g:[a, b)\to \Bbb R$ for which $\lim_{x \to b^{-}} g(x)$ does not exist, and set $f = g'$.

Then $f$ is continuous on $[a, b)$ and $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt = g(x)-g(a)$ is bounded, but $\lim_{x \to b^{-}} F(x)$ does not exist.

A simple example is $f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \sin(1/x) = -\cos(1/x)/x^2$ on $[-1, 0)$.

---

Note that the situation is different if $f$ is continuous and *bounded.* Then $F$ is *uniformly continuous,* and that implies the existence of  $\lim_{x \to b^{-}} F(x)$.

Comment: on the statement below the bar, are you referring to $f$ in my question or $f(x) = sin(\frac{1}{x})$?

Comment: It refers to your question.

Comment: @860009898987: Please let me know if anything is unclear.